# What is the best way to create SQL multiple Tables?

Tags: android, mysql, sql

I am develop app that Store to a table some Todo tasks with a - Topics and sub-topics. I thought of two ways to do this action, but what is the best way recommended. Way number 1 : is to add to my table - column with the sub-topics names, and when i want to show this specific Topic just do a for loop query for him.
way number 2 : is create 2 tables that handle the topics is and names and the other one handle the sub-topics data.

[image: If not here an Example i made:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only going to have one tag on each row, then the first method is fine.

If you are going to allow multiple tags on a row, then use a junction table, which is the `todo_tags` table in the second approach.  The junction table is the right method for storing lists of objects (`tags`) attached to another list.

Comment: So for the long term is recommended to use the second method?